# Explanation of Joint Probability and Independence

Tags: probability, independence, joint-distribution

[image: **enter image description here**]

Can anyone explain further to me the solution for the second instance where $f(x,y) = 24xy$. Specifically, I don't really understand the part "because the region in which the joint density is nonzero cannot be expressed in the form $x ∈ A, y ∈ B$".

I don't really understand how illustration with $I(x,y)$ are doing in terms of proving dependency between the variables?

Answer (score 3):

Informally, independence mean that knowing the value of one random variable gives you no extra information about the other

But if $0 \lt X+Y \lt 1$, then knowing $X=\frac34$ tells you $Y < \frac14$.  Meanwhile  knowing $X=\frac13$ tells you $Y$ can take values up to $\frac23$.  So the value of $X$ is affecting the distribution of possible values of $Y$ and thus they are not independent.  The indicator function has this effect, because it cannot be seperated into an $X$ part and a $Y$ part

Comment: Whenever you pull two things a part, there is "a rate" at which they "separate".

Comment: @Acccumulation I understand that because 0 < x+y< 1 it will cause the value of each variable to affect each other leading to some correlation right? I just don't understand why the author used a function like I(x,y). Edit: If we don't have the condition 0 < x+y < 1 then will the variables become independent?

Comment: @user277416 In your first example you have $f(x,y)=6e^{-2x}e^{-3y}I(0 \lt x, 0 \lt y)$  This can be rewritten as $\left(2e^{-2x}I(0 \lt x) \right) \left(3e^{-3y}I(0 \lt y) \right)$ as the  $I(0 \lt x, 0 \lt y)$ can be separated into $I(0 \lt x)I(0 \lt y)$.  You cannot do this with your second example

Answer (score 2):

The *necessary* (not sufficient) condition for independence is that $f(x,y)$ should be factored into something like $g(x)h(y)$. For that to happen, $I(x,y)$ should be factored like $I_A(x)I_B(y)$, but the author says that there is no way to do it, basically because of the line $0<x+y<1$.

Assume $I(x,y)=I_A(x)I_B(y)$, where $A=(0,1)$, $B=(0,1)$ (it's $(0,1)$ because there is density for $x,y$ everywhere in $(0,1)$). So, $I_A(x)$ and $I_B(y)$ should be non-zero, if for example $x=0.3,y=0.8$, but $I(x,y)$ is zero.

Comment: Right--but the question seeks an explanation of author's assertion rather than a restatement of it.  Can you show why "clearly" the indicator function does not factor?

Comment: right @whuber, I should've made it clearer

Comment: I think that it is sufficient. The issue is that the factoring fails, because the apparent factoring only holds given restrictions on the values.

Comment: So the problem is that x = 0.3 and y = 0.8 satisfy the condition of 0 < x < 1 and 0 <y < 1 but not 0 < x + y < 1 right? I thought that was the problem why these variables are not independent as the value of x will have some effect on the value of y. But I don't really get why the author used I (x,y) = 1. I see that I (x,y) will add a function where you can't separate x and y but I guess I don't understand the logic leading up to that approach, it's seem random to me and I don't see a link to the problem

Comment: @user277416 yes, that is the exact reason. I think the author chooses the harder way to explain a simple concept. The logic is probably being more algebraic rather than intuitive arguments.

Comment: @gunes so how is the I(x,y) relevant to this? I understand that it's will create a situation where you can't separate x and y but I don't see how I can do this when 0 < x+y < 1 and when we don't have that condition?

Comment: @user277416 Assume you don't have that condition, i.e. it's only $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$, then: $$I(x,y)=I_A(x)I_B(y)$$ where $I_A(x)=1$ only when $0<x<1$ and $I_B(y)=1$ only when $0<y<1$.

Answer (score 2):

A sufficient test for detecting **non**-*independence* of random variables is the *eyeball* test (described briefly in [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141641/6633) on stats.SE and in more detail in an answer on math.SE) which says that if the *support* of the joint density is *not* a rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes, then the random variables are dependent. Here, the support of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a triangle and so we can assert that the random variables are *dependent* without the need for laboriously calculating $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and then checking whether $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ equals the product $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for *all* real numbers $x$ and $y$ as the definition of independence says (or should say). That $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be expressed as $g(x)h(y)$ for *some* real numbers $x$ and $y$ (as it does in this instance) is not enough to claim independence.

Comment: it can be a combination of rectangles as well:$$\mathcal{S}=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$$

Comment: @gunes Yes, of course, but I was trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: i got downvoted or warned whenever i tried to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this makes it any easier to understand, but consider a function that's equal to $x^2y^3$ when $x<y$ and $0$ otherwise. Now consider the function $x^2y^3 (|y-x|+y-x)/(2y-2x)$. If you plot out the second function, you'll find that it's the same as the first function. It's in more complicated form, but it's in closed form rather than having a conditional definition.

While the first function appears to factor, the second one doesn't. If you want to factor out the $y^3$, you still have the $(|y-x|+y-x)/(2y-2x)$ to deal with.